# Issues while setting up diff timezones for trigger in azure data factory through java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, timezone-offset, azure-sdk-for-java

I am following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/triggers/create-or-update?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=Java) to work with azure data factory. So I am using java to work with azure data factory. And as suggested in the documentation, ScheduleTriggerRecurrence class is used to set the timezone. Below is the case for UTC timezone when it works as expected.

```
new ScheduleTriggerRecurrence()
                        .withFrequency(RecurrenceFrequency.MINUTE)
                        .withInterval(4)
                        .withStartTime(OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-06-16T00:39:13.8441801Z"))
                        .withEndTime(OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-06-16T00:55:13.8441801Z"))
                        .withTimeZone("UTC")
                        .withAdditionalProperties(mapOf())
```

And this is how it reflects on the portal which is expected.
[image]

But when we try to set diff timezone other then UTC, the call goes through successfully but on portal, the timezone is not set and the trigger seems all messed up.

This is how it looks like when a diff timezone is passed.

```
new ScheduleTriggerRecurrence()
                    .withFrequency(RecurrenceFrequency.MINUTE)
                    .withInterval(4)
                    .withStartTime(OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-06-16T00:39:13.8441801Z"))
                    .withEndTime(OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-06-16T00:55:13.8441801Z"))
                    .withTimeZone("UTC-8")
                    .withAdditionalProperties(mapOf())
```

[image]

***Is this due to bug in azure SDK or diff timezone are not supported when done through API or through SDK. I am able to udpate the timezones successfully through portal.
I have also tried by passing startTime and endTime in diff timezone but still it doesnot reflect on portal as expected.***

---

Edit 1 : Upon going through azure documents, I found that it is mentioned in docs that “For UTC time zone, format is 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ', for other time zone, format is 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'.”

But I dont see it working with ScheduleTriggerRecurrence as it need startTime and EndTime with timezone. Also, it doesnt throw any error with timezone like PST etc but when we pass the full display values like "Pacific Standard Time", then it seems to be working as expected but this is bit confusing as we have to pass the start and end time with timezone and then a separate timezone as well. Not sure, it this a bug or do

Answer (score 0):

The accepted Time Zone values are mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory#time-zone-option)

Can you try using those values?

Also, as you mentioned, instead of PST it should be `Pacific Standard Time` as PST is not the acceptable value

This is also mentioned in the link I shared above

Thanks